# How to break datetime format and show in separate text boxes using JSP code which we gets from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, jakarta-ee, datetime-format

I am cording a calendar to show events using java-ee in it. I want to retrieve datetime format data from MySQL database and show them in separate text boxes (date in one text box, time in a another text box).

The code I gave only show outputs like this (2019-04-09 13:00:00.0) I want to break this output and show them on separate boxes.

```
<body> 
    <%
        String id = (String) request.getParameter("id");
        Edit_values obj_Edit_values = new Edit_values();
        User_Bean obj_User_Bean = obj_Edit_values.get_value_of_user(id);
    %>
   <center>
        <h1>Edit Values</h1>
        <div class="page-wrapper bg-blue p-t-180 p-b-100 font-robo">
            <form action="edit_controller.jsp">

                Starting Time:<input type="text" name="start_event" value="<%=obj_User_Bean.getstart_event()%>"><br>
                Ending Time:<input type="text" name="end_event" value="<%=obj_User_Bean.getend_event()%>"><br>

                <input type="submit" value="Edit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
<body>
```

I want the outputs like

```
Date = 2019-04-09
time = 13:00:00.0
```

not like 2019-04-09 13:00:00.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support Anilm
but below code works with my case.

```
<html>
   <body>

        <%
            //Start Event Split
            String start_event = "2019-04-09 13:00:00.0";
            String[] start_parts = start_event.split(" ");
            String start_date = start_parts[0];
            String start_time = start_parts[1];

            //End Event Split
            String end_event = "2019-04-10 13:00:00.0");
            String[] end_parts = end_event.split(" ");
            String end_date = end_parts[0];
            String end_time = end_parts[1];
        %>
        <form action="edit_controller.jsp">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Ending Date" name="end_date" value="<%=end_date%>">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Starting Date" name="start_date" value="<%=start_date%>">
          <input type="Time" placeholder="Starting Time" name="start_time" value="<%=start_time%>">
          <input type="Time" placeholder="Ending Time" name="end_time" value="<%=end_time%>">
          </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As per your question i just put that in textbox in js.In your question how am i supposed to get this obj_User_Bean.getstart_event() value.Thats why i presented that in Js.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to your question,this will work.

```js
var str="2019-04-09 13:00:00.0";
str=str.split(' ');
document.getElementById("t1").value = str[0];
document.getElementById("t2").value = str[1];
```

```html
Date: <input type="text" id=t1 name="date"><br>
Time: <input type="text" id=t2 name="time"><br>
```